# Dell Inspiron 15-3552 - Have I Found Fix (Factory State Restore) for Trashed 14.04 Desktop?

Tags: 14.04, dell, inspiron, recovery-mode

After a failed general software update this new laptop's factory-installed 14.04 is sickly.

If I M-for-manual-recovery past the "An error occurred while mounting /boot/efi." message I get on startup I get to a screen with messages "File system check or mount failed.", "A maintenance shell will now be started.", etc. Entering the root password, forcing a shutdown, then starting-up again takes me to a GNU GRUB version 2.02 screen with options including "Restore Ubuntu 14.04 to factory state". The other options are "Ubuntu" (the default), "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and "System setup".

I haven't tried restoring to factory state yet as I'd be interested to see a Boot-Info report first, but I'm having problems getting to this as discussed in two other related questions.

So it does, after all, appear that it's possible to restore the OS to as-shipped state and there's a Dell recovery partition.  I haven't yet worked out how to look at partitions, etc in Ubuntu so I may remove the HDD and have a look with some Windows tools I'm familiar with.

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - In the title!  I posted this question seeking helpful comments and because I thought this information might be useful to others having similar problems. There may be better ways of posting helpful info but I'm new to Ubuntu and askubuntu.com so am still learning. I am a bit surprised that neither Dell nor askubuntu.com were able quickly to direct me to this apparently straightforward solution when I posted my first-ever question less than a week ago.

Comment: If you take some time to get familiar with this site's q&a format you will not be surprised in future.